-bash: /usr/local/bin/vnstat: No such file or directory
I installed vnstat manually and remove it and the issue is when I run vnstat I am always getting after installing it using apt-get start to show this issue
> root@host:~# vnstat
> -bash: /usr/local/bin/vnstat: No such file or directory 

any solution for this issue

The path is probably hashed by your shell - see Remove path to uninstalled codeblocks

It also may help in the future when installing things manually from source packages to use ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc instead of just ./configure for getting the binaries under /usr/bin instead of /usr/local/bin.
